# How to use Mongo Java driver @BsonCreator annotation?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, morphia, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to map an **immutable** object from MongoDB to my Java POJO and i keep getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: 
No usable constructor for com.example.model.Item
```

It seems that when using immutable objects, I need to annotate using @BsonCreator however that doesn't appear to be working and I believe that might be because using this annotation requires me to somehow configure `org.bson.codecs.pojo.Conventions#ANNOTATION_CONVENTION`. Maybe I'm blind but i can't seem to find any examples anywhere on how to configure this. Any help would be greately appreciated. Here is my annotated POJO:

```
@Value /* Lombok auto generates getters */
@Builder /* Lombok auto generates builder method */
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private final @NotNull AnEnum type;
    private final int refId;
    private final int quantity;

    @BsonCreator
    public Item(@BsonProperty("type") AnEnum type,
                @BsonProperty("refId") int refId,
                @BsonProperty("quantity") int quantity) {
        this.type = type;
        this.refId = refId;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Morphia or just the pure Java driver? @BsonCreator is part of the driver, but you've added the [morphia] keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should definitely work with the POJO support. I've just made a [test case on github](https://github.com/niccottrell/mongo-java-tests/blob/a1b5d20b273a30d4c7ee0d868afbdcb5755e689b/src/test/PojoImmutableTest.java) which passes.

I note two issues:

1. `implements Serializable` should not be necessary
2. **you will need to specify getters for those 3 fields for the automatic codec builder to pick them up correctly.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My problem was that i didn't realize which annotations are part of which library so i was mixing the ones from Morhpia with Spring data and the mongo driver. This was a non issue when i moved to Spring data's mapping annotation @Document as it doesn't seem to need an annotation as long as i created a private, seemingly useless, no param constructor for an immutable multi param object.

Answer (score 0):

try to add an empty constructor, seems that Morphia needs those, at least in my project it helps. Please let me know if it fixed it for you.

Comment: Adding a default constructor definitely works and is a usable workaround, however it feels messy. The developers seem to have provided `@BsonCreator` specifically for this purpose yet the documentation and examples seem to be lacking.